# react app doesn't update and .env file doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I'm in WSL2, and my react app does not update any changes at all, only updates when re-running "npm start"

I've tried "npm install react-dotenv" and creating an .env file with
FAST_REFRESH=false
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
doesn't work

tried in the package.json
"start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start"
doesn't work

any suggestions? I don't even mind manually refreshing the browser, it's just that it won't update unless I restart the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to install an additional dotenv package since Create-React-App already supports environment variables natively. However if you use environment variables, you need to prefix them with `REACT_APP`. e. g. `REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE`.

Also note: Whenever you update an environment variable you have to restart the app.

Take a look at the official [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Now for the reloading problem. There are a couple of possible solutions:

- Add a `.env` file to your project without third party package and
  define a variable named `FAST_REFRESH=false`. ([CRA advanced
  configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/))
- If you are using a Virtual Machine try adding `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to your `.env` file.
- There is another common problem in CRA ^17.0.1 with hot reloading ([Github issue - Hot Reload stopped working with React "^17.0.1"](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904))

  ```
  if (module.hot) module.hot.accept();
  ```
- Finally (**and this is the most likely solution in my opinion**) try to move your project folder to somewhere, where npm can automatically recompile in WSL. E. g. move project from your desktop to your actual home directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate, I tried everything but nothing worked. it just doesn't detect changes unless I do npm start again.